# How stable is the git plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

I was intending to have a play with git, and was wondering if anyone had used the [git plugin for eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

I see it's at version 0.3.1, and was wondering if anyone knew how stable it was / any gotchas?

---

Update:

If you are using a recent version of Eclipse, your Help menu has an 'Eclipse Marketplace...' link.

Enter 'git' in the Find field. This shows me EGit.

This is also very high in the Popular plugins list.

Click install. Much easier than having to add update site locations by hand.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[Github blog](http://github.com/blog/232-github-and-eclipse) spoke yesterday about Egit plugin:

http://freshmeat.net/projects/jgit/

Comment: And it's stable now.. bundled with Eclipse Indigo 3.7

Comment: No thanks: "**This package might eat your files.**  Everything I've added to a  repository with it has unpacked properly both with itself and  with the canonical C based implementation, but that doesn't mean  it won't generate a corrupt object." (from the README)

Answer (score 32):

I'm using if for day-to-day work and I find it stable. Lately the plugin has made good progress and has added:

- merge support, including a in-Eclipse merge tool;
- a basic synchronise view;
- reading of .git/info/exclude and .gitignore files.
- rebasing;
- streamlined commands for pushing and pulling;
- cherry-picking.

[image: Git repositories view]

Be sure to skim the [EGit User Guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide) for a good overview of the current functionality.

I find that I only need to drop to the comand line for interactive rebases.

As [an official Eclipse project](http://eclipse.org/egit/) I am confident that EGit will receive all the main features of the command-line client.

Comment: Two year later and EGit still lacks some important features like client hooks (Bug 299315) or submodules (Bug 314853) and suffers from some grave bugs like switching branches (Bug 345585). I do not understand, why EGit has to reinvent the wheel and implement it's own JGit instead using command line git.

Comment: To be cross-platform, duuuh. I guess this isn't the case with Mercurial, Subversion, or CVS.

Answer (score 20):

EGit is still in eclipse incubation. You can install it using the Eclipse update manager.

1. Select Help -> Install New Software...
2. You probably do not have the JGit update URL in your list of sites so in the 'Work with:' field enter this url: http://www.jgit.org/updates
3. Click Add...
4. You should now see Eclipse Git Plugin - Integration Build (Incubation) listed as available software to install. Check it and click Next.
5. Click Next and agree to the license and it should be installed.

Comment: This somehow does not work for Snow Leopard running Eclipse (64-bit). The Git item does not show up in the Import menu or anywhere. :-(

Comment: On Lion also, it is a bad idea to do this. Git does not appear in the menu and various small details have been messed up in the ADT variant of Eclipse. A reinstall seems now to be necessary.

Answer (score 9):

You can integrate Git-GUI with Eclipse as an alternative to EGit.

See this two part YouTube tutorial specific to Windows:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcM1xOiaidk
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1OrPJClD92s

Answer (score 6):

It still seems barely usable, to tell the truth, especially in comparison to the CVS and SVN plugins. Is it really GIT so different that developer with four years of CVS and SVN plugin experience should be completely lost with completely different GUI, unheard commands, two or even single word error messages and "features" like overwriting the shared repository without warning? Do not use it, use command line interface. If you do not like command line interface, do not use GIT at all.

Comment: I am sorry to say I have to agree with you completely, looking at another solution outside of Eclipse which pains me to have to leave my IDE just for source control commands.

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile EclipseGit is an "Official Eclipse Technology Project" ([09-05-07 GitWiki](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/EclipsePlugin)). I use the current **version 0.5.0** (the Wiki is a step behind the development) from time to time, without any problems. Version comparison, commit, revert etc. is working well, although manual refresh's (F5) are necessary when using command line or other Git clients (usual and acceptable Eclipse behavior I think).

Answer (score 5):

For a command line view from within eclipse, install the Aptana Eclipse Plugin, it provides you with a console. It's an incredible productivity boost if you do a lot of terminal commands.

Comment: Aptana has now direct support for Git.

Answer (score 3):

I've set up EGit in Eclipse for a few of my projects and find that its a lot easier, faster to use a command line interface versus having to drill down menus and click around windows.

I would prefer something like a command line view within Eclipse to do all the Git duties.

Answer (score 3):

egit has a serious bug when comparing a file in your working dir with an earlier - it flashes a blank tab. The bug has been around since 2010 and still has not been fixed.
This very basic feature which works very well in svn plugin is completely broken.

Answer (score 2):

I've used it briefly, but it was still lacking support in several important areas (it wasn't doing renames/moves properly, or something). There also was no update site available for it.

I don't remember which version it was, but this was like 6 months ago. Hopefully it is better now.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in these pointers: http://github.com/blog/232-github-and-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

There is also [gitclipse](http://gitclipse.sourceforge.net/index.php)(based on JavaGit), but seems dead.