# source safe for android

Tags: android, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

As we know that  for vb.net , to backup & link project `visual source safe` are available but i havent idea about android. i need same thing for android, from where we can save & get project work

**Update:** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CVS, Subversion, ...

If you want to use VSS with Eclipse, you can download this [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vssplugin/).

Comment: I can't read it. Please update your image with only the parameters's window.

Comment: You can try to map a drive to your server instead of using the UNC... (V:\ instead of \\...)

Comment: Hello, i have android studio, is there any plugin available or any other way for implement VSS ?

Answer (score 2):

Strongly recommend that you look carefully as [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/) to fill the role that source safe currently has for you. Eclipse is very well integrated to both of these two systems.

These modern source control systems are probably more complex than you are accustomed to using but you will find the learning curve fairly flat after initial set up and the benefits (even for a small project) become clear very quickly.

Stack overflow [thread on GIT and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302089/git-plugin-for-eclipse).

Comment: What do you use for Git integration with Eclipse?

Comment: I in fact use GIT raw but have added a link to a thread regarding this. Thanks