# Eclipse Plugin for Git - EGIT vs Aptana

Tags: eclipse, git

I am new to GIT and I have been looking for a GIT plugin for Eclipse. 
I came across this on SO .
[How stable is the git plugin for eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302089/how-stable-is-the-git-plugin-for-eclipse) and also http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-Eclipse-plugin-to-manage-git

But these have worsened my confusion over using EGIT or Aptana.
I just want to know

```
1)Why should one use EGIT and why should one use Aptana.
2)What are the differences in performance and stability in both ?
3) Which one is better right now with their latest releases?
```

Kindly, please answer these questions. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like aptana and egit are different, aptana is a whole ide based on eclipse with a custom git plugin, and egit is a git plugin for eclipse.

I'm using egit with git console and so far, it fit my needs :)
You should start using one, then if you're not happy with it, try another one.

The git command line is really great, because it does exactly what you tell it to do. At first it's not really user friendly but it's learning efficient and you know what you do. sometimes plugin do other things that are not expected (not in the wrong way but it can cause problems)